# confusion on Picard's theorem when solution exists and when it's unique

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am totally confused when it comes to Picard's theorem and it's solution whether it exists and if it's unique...the more I read into the more I get confused..How would I identify when it exists and when it's unique ?

let's say I have a problem here

$$t \cdot \frac{dy}{dt} + y = 2; y(0)=1$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 2-\frac{y}{t}$$

$$f(t,y) = 2 - \frac{y}{t}$$

$$f(y) = \frac{-1}{t}$$

we could say that $f(t,y)$ and $f(y)$ are continuous except at $t=0$`

for something like this when would the solution exist and when wouldn't exist? Same with solution that is unique, when would it be unique and when wouldn't it be ?

Comment: The theorem gives sufficient conditions, so either the hypotheses apply or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If a theorem says "under conditions.... the solution exists", **and** you checked that each of those conditions holds, then the solution exists.
- If a theorem says "under conditions.... the solution is unique", **and** you checked that each of those conditions holds, then the solution is unique.

Neither of the above apply to your situation, because the right-hand side in $y'=f(t,y)$ has division by $t$, which is a rather bad thing to do when $t$ is near $0$. The function $f$ is not continuous itself, so neither of two standard theorems (Peano or Lipschitz) apply. This means you are on your own; you have to reach a conclusion without being helped by those theorems.

Hint: assuming the solution exists, what do you get by plugging $t=0$ and $y=1 $ into $t \frac{dy}{dt}+y=2$? Does this look like a contradiction? If assuming something leads you to a contradiction, that assumption was false.